# TableView editing style

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview, editing

I've got a tableView with entries which the user should be able to edit. The special thing is, the tableView has a "right detail" style (a number) and I want this right detail to be replaced (animated if possible) with the standard disclosure indicator accessory, when the user hits edit.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Update: Thank you for the answers so far but could you maybe give me a code example for the part where the number gets replaced by the picture? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the UITableViewDelegate methods for editing such as `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` to perform your changes. Use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get the UITableViewCell object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom cell here and do all those works. Here you can use the same cell and add a subview to that cell where you want that change to happen. Later depending on the state i.e; isEditing = True/ false you can display what you want.

Comment: create a new class , inherit form UITableViewCell class.
Then add Subviews to the view of the newly created class like
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView:label];
[self.view bringSubViewToFront];
Now in cellForRowIndex in your class 
CustomCell * cell = [CustomCell alloc]initWith dequeReusableIdentifier:@"sample"];
return cell;
You can add different subviews in the same positions and then hide and unhide them on click or timing by

Comment: cell.label.hidden = YES|NO;